# Is the AWS.net library compatible with MonoTouch?

Tags: sdk, amazon-s3, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a new app using MonoTouch and I'd like to store data in AWS.

I saw there is an AWS.net library available from Amazon, but I don't know if I can use it with my MonoTouch app. Can I?

Comment: Where are these libraries, I would like to take a look

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza: You can find them at http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

standard .NET binaries won't work, per FAQ: http://monotouch.net/FAQ (Can I use standard desktop Mono assemblies or .NET assemblies with MonoTouch?).

Edited: All you need to do is rebuild the source code with Mono's C# compiler

Answer (score 2):

I think the better option is to use the [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) and write [bindings](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types) to the Obj-c library. There are examples out there of how to write bindings if you just do a search for it. It probably isn't the quick solution you were hoping for but you probably don't want to use the SDK for .NET anyway as it probably wasn't intended to be used on the iPhone.

If you do end up writing bindings for it, please post it on github for everyone else to use. Solve once for many, right? :)

Answer (score 2):

For standard upload of files from monotouch to S3 I used this [Library](http://aws.amazon.com/code/130) ,
recompiled in MonoDevelop using MonoTouch Library Template and done  ( use System.Web.Services instead of System.Web ).

Recompile AWS for monotouch has to be really difficult because of the heavy use of System.Web and IOrderedDictionary ( ThirdParty Libraries ).

Answer (score 0):

I just built the AWS SDK for Monotouch/Mono for Android. I had to modify some files and add some classes from the current Mono release.

GitHub repo is located here:

https://github.com/fr500/aws_sdk_monotouch_monodroid

It's my first attempt at this, and it's working but I don't know if my approach is correct. Any help will be appreciated