# Accessing S3 from a MonoDroid application

Tags: amazon-s3, xamarin.android

**Is there any solution for accessing S3 (or any AWS services) from a MonoDroid application?** I have found the Android sdk for S3 but those are jar files (not sure if there is some way to make this work?)

I tried using the .NET AWS SDK. This compiles but at runtime when I try to construct any object it does all kinds of strange things (Breaks like an exception occurred but no indication what the exception is, sometimes will crash VS all together)

I searched the AWS docs to see if there is a simple web service post I can make without an SDK, it seems like this should be possible, but I haven't found any information on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access S3 using the [REST API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?APIRest.html). Other AWS services have similar API's.

Another solution would be to recompile the .Net SDK with the Mono c# compiler. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356151/is-the-aws-net-library-compatible-with-monotouch/5357747#5357747) which suggests this solution - the accepted answer was edited by [@Miguel de Icaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16929/miguel-de-icaza) (I think he knows a thing or two about MonoDroid... )

However, this solution potentially has a serious flaw. You should never use your S3 secret key from a client device. This won't be an issue if your app users are entering their own credentials but if you are planning on using your own S3 account with multiple users then you have a problem.

With the REST API, you can pre-sign requests on a server and therefore never expose your secret key on the client.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the clear explanation and +10 for the tip on the secret key. I was looking for the REST API documentation last night, figuring it existed, but must have just missed it.